# Can we deploy Azure automation account and runbook through Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm developing an MVC application which communicates with Azure. As part of this I have to deploy some Azure components through visual studio. I have already deployed logic apps through visual studio using the Azure logic app tools downloaded from Market place. I now need to deploy a scheduled runbook. Do we have a way to deploy Automation account and runbook through Visual Studio?

I have checked the Visual studio installer and Visual Studio Market Place. I could not identify a relevant source.

Comment: Seams it's impossible for visual studio, take a look at this [user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-azure-automation/suggestions/6004439-provide-visual-studio-authoring-capabilities). It's only available for vs code and powershell ISE now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Azure Resource Group" project and use the ARM templates for creating/deploying the Automation account and runbook using Visual Studio.

Please refer to below json which can be updated in azuredeploy.json to create/deploy both automation account and runbook.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "2.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "accountName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "samplePowerShellRunbookName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "samplePowerShellRunbookDescription": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "samplePowerShellRunbookContentUri": {
      "type": "String"
    }

  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('accountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "Basic"
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "runbooks",
          "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
          "name": "[parameters('samplePowerShellRunbookName')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {},
          "properties": {
            "runbookType": "PowerShell",
            "logProgress": "false",
            "logVerbose": "false",
            "description": "[parameters('samplePowerShellRunbookDescription')]",
            "publishContentLink": {
              "uri": "[parameters('samplePowerShellRunbookContentUri')]",
              "version": "1.0.0.0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.